# Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: PC0YG9X9Z9CXRFV9, Extended Request ID)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I did the following :

#### Step 1: Setting Up AWS SDK

1. Added the AWS SDK dependency to your `pom.xml` file:

   ```xml
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
           <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.29</version> <!-- use the latest version -->
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
2. If you're not using Maven, download the AWS SDK for Java and include it in your project's classpath.

#### Step 2: Setting Up IAM User

1. Log in to the AWS Management Console.
2. Navigate to the IAM dashboard.
3. Create a new IAM user with programmatic access and attach policies that grant the necessary permissions for working with S3 (like `AmazonS3FullAccess`).
4. Note down the access key ID and secret access key for this user.

#### Step 3: Configuring Credentials

Configure your credentials using one of the following methods:

1. **Environment Variables**: Set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables.
2. **AWS Credentials File**: Create an AWS credentials file at `~/.aws/credentials` (Linux & Mac) or `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\credentials` (Windows) with the following content:

   ```
   [default]
   aws_access_key_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
   aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
   ```

#### Step 4: Writing Java Code to Upload Files

1. Initialize the S3 client.

   ```
   public class S3Config {

       @Bean
       public S3Client s3Client() {
           S3Client client = S3Client.builder()
                   .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
                   .build();
           return client;
       }

   }

   public void putObject(String bucketName, String key, byte[] files) {
       PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
               .bucket(bucketName)
               .key(key)
               .build();    
       PutObjectResponse putObjectResponse = s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(files));
       putObjectResponse.toString();
   }
   ```

Iam using the below code to test

```
@Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(S3Service s3Service) {
        return args -> {
            s3Service.putObject("flexcoreobjectstore",
                    "foo",
                    "hello world".getBytes());

            byte[] foos = s3Service.getObject("flexcoreobjectstore", "foo");

            System.out.println(new String(foos));
        };
    }
```

But I am getting this error :

```
  Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: PC0YG9X9Z9CXRFV9, Extended Request ID: WlrLIh6/j9Xd8vhRL9Xtt5dPO4n56WE4cLT8MLX2CFiG1COgbNapseovy47L4sTd4s4SBoA4lNevEYqH6GAhfQ==)
```

Any suggestions for the steps I am missing?

Comment: did you create the bucket before testing?

Comment: Yes i created the bucket correctly

Comment: did you give correct IAM permission to the user account to write to S3?

Comment: Yes. Iam using the root account. It is for testing. Root account has all access right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct for AWS SDK for Java v2. Looking at this code

```
public void putObject(String bucketName, String key, byte[] files) {
    PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();    
    PutObjectResponse putObjectResponse = s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(files));
    putObjectResponse.toString();
```

Your error suggests that the AWS credentials used to make the S3 request do not have the necessary permissions to perform the **putObject** operation. Make sure that the user whose creds you are using has the correct permissions for S3.